# Connect an application to type of ODBC driver 32 and 64

Tags: vb.net, excel, odbc

I am stuck with this scenario,
I am developing VB application to import data from excel file to Oracle DB on a system runs win7 64 and office 32.
connection to the oracle will be through ODBC.
The issue here that I am not able to connect to both odbc driver at the same time, office driver is 32 and Oracle driver is 64
if the app runs in 64 mode it recognizes Oracle DSN but not the office , and if it runs in 32 mode it will connect to office but not oracle.
any idea how to fix this, 
please note that making the connection to oracle through odbc is a MUST

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a specific example of your problem, including the relevant code. Otherwise it is difficult to precisely understand your problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Target CPU" to x86?

Comment: I would create a windows service that is build for the 64 cpu, and offers an interface to upload the data to the oracle db, and a 32 application that can connect to your webservice. You could then receive the data in a x86 application GUI application, which then connects to your webservice, that connects with 64 oracle driver. This way your implementation is abstracted, and it wouldn't be a "big" deal to change it at a later stage, in case you decide to switch either of the 2 at a later from 32 to 64...

Answer (score 0):

So get a 32 bit ODBC driver for Oracle or a 64 bit ODBC driver for office.

Alternatively, get an ODBC-ODBC Bridge - they can bridge between 32 bit applications and 64 bit drivers.